# cumsum the opposite of diff in r

Tags: r

I have a question and I'm not sure if I'm being totally stupid here or if this is a genuine problem, or if I've misunderstood what these functions do.

Is the opposite of diff the same as cumsum? I thought it was. However, using this example:

```
dd <- c(17.32571,17.02498,16.71613,16.40615,
        16.10242,15.78516,15.47813,15.19073,
        14.95551,14.77397)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(dd)
plot(cumsum(diff(dd)))

> dd
 [1] 17.32571 17.02498 16.71613 16.40615 16.10242 15.78516 15.47813 15.19073 14.95551
[10] 14.77397
> cumsum(diff(dd))
[1] -0.30073 -0.60958 -0.91956 -1.22329 -1.54055 -1.84758 -2.13498 -2.37020 -2.55174
```

These aren't the same. Where have I gone wrong?

AHHH! Fridays.

Obviously

Comment: cumsum(x) returns a vector of length(x), with each element i being the sum of x[1:i]

Comment: The opposite of `cumsum` would be `Reduce('-', dd, accumulate=T)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions are quite different: `diff(x)` returns a vector of length `(length(x)-1)` which contains the difference between one element and the next in a vector `x`, while `cumsum(x)` returns a vector of length equal to the length of `x` containing the sum of the elements in `x`

Example:

```
x <- c(1:10)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> diff(x)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
v <- cumsum(x)
> v
#[1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

The function `cumsum()` is the cumulative sum and therefore the entries of the vector `v[i]` that it returns are a result of all elements in `x` between `x[1]` and `x[i]`. In contrast, `diff(x)` only takes the difference between one element `x[i]` and the next, `x[i+1]`.

The combination of `cumsum` and `diff` leads to different results, depending on the order in which the functions are executed:

```
> cumsum(diff(x))
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Here the result is the cumulative sum of a sequence of nine "1". Note that if this result is compared with the original vector `x`, the last entry `10` is missing.

On the other hand, by calculating

```
> diff(cumsum(x))
# 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

one obtains a vector that is again similar to the original vector `x`, but now the first entry `1` is missing.

In none of the cases the original vector is restored, therefore it cannot be stated that `cumsum()` is the opposite or inverse function of `diff()`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to account for the impact of the first element

dd == c(dd[[1]], dd[[1]] + cumsum(diff(dd)))

Comment: @Pierre Lafortune, I think you have misread the command, I have added only the first element. In fact, the line is equivalent to:

`dd[[1]] + c(0, cumsum(diff(dd))`

Comment: maybe more simply `cumsum(c(dd[1],diff(dd)))`

Answer (score 3):

@RHertel answered it well, stating that `diff()` returns a vector with `length(x)-1`.

Therefore, another simple workaround would be to add `0` to the beginning of the original vector so that `diff()` computes the difference between `x[1]` and `0`.

```
> x <- 5:10

> x
#[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10

> diff(x)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1

> diff(c(0,x))
#[1] 5 1 1 1 1 1
```

This way it is possible to use `diff()` with `c()` as a representation of the inverse of `cumsum()`

```
> cumsum(diff(c(0,x)))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> diff(c(0,cumsum(x)))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of "lag" and "difference".

```
x<-5:10
y<-diff(x,lag=1,difference=1)    
z<-diffinv(y,lag=1,differences = 1,xi=5) #xi is first value.
k<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,z))
k
   x  z
1  5  5
2  6  6
3  7  7
4  8  8
5  9  9
6 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Cumsum is not the opposite of diff. The opposite of diff is **Discrete Integration** (Inverse of diff). It's a tiny bit different from cumsum: Here's the function:
*diffinv(x)*

Let's make an example out of your data:

```
dd <- c(17.32571,17.02498,16.71613,16.40615,
        16.10242,15.78516,15.47813,15.19073,
        14.95551,14.77397)
> diffinv(dd)
 [1]   0.00000  17.32571  34.35069  51.06682  67.47297  83.57539  99.36055 114.83868 130.02941 144.98492 159.75889
> cumsum(dd)
 [1]  17.32571  34.35069  51.06682  67.47297  83.57539  99.36055 114.83868 130.02941 144.98492 159.75889
```

The resulting vectors are almost identical, but diffinv() result starts with 0.

If I run your script and compare simple *dd* call with *cumsum(diff(dd))* or *diffinv(diff(dd))* result, they are very different.

```
> dd
 [1] 17.32571 17.02498 16.71613 16.40615 16.10242 15.78516 15.47813 15.19073 14.95551 14.77397
> cumsum(diff(dd))
[1] -0.30073 -0.60958 -0.91956 -1.22329 -1.54055 -1.84758 -2.13498 -2.37020 -2.55174
> diffinv(diff(dd))
 [1]  0.00000 -0.30073 -0.60958 -0.91956 -1.22329 -1.54055 -1.84758 -2.13498 -2.37020 -2.55174
```

But if you **reverse the order of the functions** like so, you get a result, that is similar to what was (assumingly) expected:

```
> dd
 [1] 17.32571 17.02498 16.71613 16.40615 16.10242 15.78516 15.47813 15.19073 14.95551 14.77397
> diff(diffinv(dd))
 [1] 17.32571 17.02498 16.71613 16.40615 16.10242 15.78516 15.47813 15.19073 14.95551 14.77397
> diff(cumsum(dd))
[1] 17.02498 16.71613 16.40615 16.10242 15.78516 15.47813 15.19073 14.95551 14.77397
```

Note that in this example, *diff(diffinv(dd))* gives the **same result** as a simple *dd* call, and not the function call using *cumsum()*.